# Making AForge VideoCaptureDevice work with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, aforge

I'm trying to make a camera show on a plane in Unity3D. I'm using code from the AForge documentation: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/f4d3c2ba-605c-f066-f969-68260ce5e141.htm
except I'm inserting a webcam through Unity instead of AForges usual way, where it wants to make FilterInfoCollection. If I'm not wrong this is needed for Unity to recognize the webcam.

However my code is not working what so ever, the webcam starts (because of my webCam.Play()), but nothing else happens. By debugging I figured the program wasn't reaching my video_NewFrame function, where I believe I need to initialize in some way when I'm using Unity?

How do I set this up properly?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Imaging.Filters;
using AForge.Imaging;
using AForge;

public class LoadVideo : MonoBehaviour {

    public VideoCaptureDevice videoSource;
    WebCamTexture webCam;
    void Start(){
        webCam = new WebCamTexture();
        webCam.Play();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    object b;
    public WebCamDevice wc;
    public GameObject originalFeed;
    void Update () {
        videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(webCam.deviceName);
        videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
        videoSource.Start();
        originalFeed.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = originalFeedTexture;
    }
    public delegate void EventPrototype(System.EventArgs args);

    Texture2D originalFeedTexture;
    void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Debug.Log("you here mate");
        Bitmap video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        video.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] bitmapRecord = memoryStream.ToArray();

        originalFeedTexture.LoadImage(bitmapRecord);
    }

}
```

Comment: What version of `AForge` are you using?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria 2.2.5

Comment: I have problems with `2.2.5` and downgrade to `2.2.0` (in my case the event was never raised).

Comment: Just made a test with a 2.2.0 downgrade, exact same issue.

Comment: Why are you using AForge to access the camera frames?

Comment: Can this be done otherwise, solely using Unity?

Comment: The question is: What are you doing?

Comment: I am trying to split the camera into frames, on which I then can use AForges methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am not sure that *AForge* will work in Unity. The reason is because it uses .NET 4 or more while Unity uses .NET 3.5.

Other than this, there are several problems in your code.

**1**.`WebCamTexture` is used by *Unity* to start capturing frames from the camera.

**2**.`VideoCaptureDevice` is used by *AForge* to start capturing frames from the camera.

**The 4 Problems**:

**1**.You have to use one not both. You can't combine both of them and I believe that the camera can be accessed from one location at a time.

When you did `webCam.Play();` then `videoSource.Start();`, you are trying to use one camera from multiple API. The `VideoCaptureDevice` should be used if you want to use *AForge* API.

**2**.You are calling `videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(webCam.deviceName);` and starting the camera with `videoSource.Start();` every frame in the `Update` function. That should be done once by moving it to the `Start` function. You also need to register to the `NewFrame` event once.

**3**. `originalFeedTexture` is not initialized but is used in the `video_NewFrame` and `Update` function.

**4**.You can get the webcam names with the [`WebCamDevice`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamDevice.html) class. The example code at the end shows how. Don't use `WebCamTexture` for that.

**5**.It is extremely likely that `videoSource.NewFrame` is invoked/called from another `Thread`. So, when your `video_NewFrame` function is called, the `originalFeedTexture.LoadImage(bitmapRecord);` line of code will throw an exception that looks like this:

> .... can only be called from the main thread

You can have to find a way to call that line of code in Unity's main Thread or the Update function since you can't use Unity API(Texture2D/originalFeedTexture) in another `Thread`.

Start with the code below, maybe you can get it working. Not sure about this whole *AForge*+*Unity* thing due to `.NET` version difference. Problem **#5** is not fixed in this solution. You can use [*Unity Threading Helper*](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-threading-helper.90128/) plugin(free) for that.

```
public class LoadVideo : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public VideoCaptureDevice videoSource;
    public GameObject originalFeed;
    Texture2D originalFeedTexture;

    void Start()
    {
        init();
    }

    void init()
    {
        originalFeedTexture = new Texture2D(128, 128);

        //Get WebCam names
        WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
        if (devices.Length <= 0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No Web Cam Found....Exiting");
            return; //Exit
        }
        videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(devices[0].name);
        videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
        videoSource.Start();
    }

    void stop()
    {
        videoSource.SignalToStop();
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        originalFeed.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = originalFeedTexture;
    }

    public delegate void EventPrototype(System.EventArgs args);

    void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Debug.Log("you here mate");
        Bitmap video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        video.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] bitmapRecord = memoryStream.ToArray();

        originalFeedTexture.LoadImage(bitmapRecord);
    }

    //Make sure to stop when run time ends
    void OnDisable()
    {
        stop();
    }
}
```

> I am trying to split the camera into frames, on which I then can use
>   AForges methods.

If that's all you want to do, you can use Unity's `WebCamTexture` then convert it to `Texture2D`:

```
WebCamTexture webCam = new WebCamTexture (160, 120);
webCam.play();
Texture2D originalFeedTexture = new Texture2D(webCam.width, webCam.height);
originalFeedTexture.SetPixels(webCam.GetPixels());
originalFeedTexture.Apply();
///Use it  then destroy it
Object.Destroy(originalFeedTexture);
```

The frame is now stored in the `originalFeedTexture` variable.
If you need the `Texture2D` frames as bytes, maybe for sending over network:

[`JPG`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.EncodeToJPG.html) bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = originalFeedTexture.EncodeToJPG();
```

[`PNG`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.EncodeToPNG.html) bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = originalFeedTexture.EncodeToPNG();
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! I tried your first piece of code, it doesn't give any errors, but the camera doesn't activate either. I agree there might be an issue between AForge and Unity, but I have a few remarks. I tested AForge beforehand with some grayscale functions on a loaded image, which worked fine. If this indeed is an AForge issue, would it be possible to fix by downgrading to a later version? I'm gonna test your second piece of code soon, as that might do the trick. Kind regards

Comment: "I tested AForge beforehand with some grayscale functions on a loaded image, which worked fine" The AForge API is divided into modules. Some modules uses the new `.NET API` Unity does not support. Others don't use API from `.NET API` and therefore should work fine. An example of this is the async/await keyword. I expect the image manipulation API to be independent and does not even need  `.NET 4  API`. Maybe, find lowe version then build it with `.NET 3.5` or less. One important thing to do is to **place all the DLL of AForge in the Asset folder**.

Comment: I see that you accepted this answer. Please tell me what happens. I also think you should check [this](https://forum.unity3d.com/forums/experimental-scripting-previews.107/) out. Unity is testing their `.NET 4.6`. You many want to download that and try it. By the way, it works in the Editor only for now. Standalone build support will be added in few months.

Comment: I accepted your comment based on the splitting frame code you posted at the end, as it basically fixed my issue. Using that I'm able to make the frames from a byte[] array into a Bitmap, and then use AForges methods on that bitmap. To answer your question: what happens? Nothing visually happens with the above code. The camera doesn't activate, but it doesn't show any errors either.

Comment: Ok. Good to know which one solved your ptoblem. When I have time, I will download AForge and see if I can get it working with the current Unity .NET version